# Como adicionar conteúdo ao ListBox do Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, listbox

Olá, estou com uma dúvida em um código para Excel VBA. Quero que o código busque na planilha o mesmo número que foi digitado no `TextBox`, depois de achar ele manda as informações da linha inteira da planilha para a `ListBox`. Como o código está contido na sub rotina `AfterUpdate` do `Textbox`, ele reseta o conteúdo da `ListBox` reescrevendo toda vez na linha 0. Não sei se fui claro. Desde já agradeço.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()

    Dim linhalistbox As Integer
    Dim linha As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim total As Double

    linhalistbox = 0
    linha = 2
    i = 1
    total = 0

    Do Until Plan2.Cells(linha, 1) = ""
        If TextBox1.Text = Plan2.Cells(linha, 1) Then
            With Me.ListBox1
            .AddItem
            .List(linhalistbox, 0) = i
            .List(linhalistbox, 1) = Plan2.Cells(linha, 3)
            .List(linhalistbox, 2) = Plan2.Cells(linha, 4)
            TextBox2.Text = i
            TextBox5.Text = Plan2.Cells(linha, 4)
            total = total + CDec(TextBox5.Text)
            TextBox6.Text = total
            linhalistbox = linhalistbox + 1
            i = i + 1
            End With
        End If
        linha = linha + 1
    Loop

   TextBox1.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problema**

Estás definir os elementos na listbox a partir do item com índice 0

```
Dim linhalistbox As Integer
linhalistbox = 0
```

**Solução:**

Inicializa a variável com o total de elementos já presentes na ListBox

```
Dim linhalistbox As Integer
linhalistbox = Me.ListBox1.ListCount
```